# Copy file from one remote server to another remote server using nested delegate_to

Tags: ansible

As a user I want to copy file from node1 to node2. Is it possible with copy module + delegate_to

Below is what I was trying to do. Playbook is running from node3.

```
Playbook Sample

---
- name: Gather Facts for all hosts
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  any_errors_fatal: true
  become: true

- name: Test
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  any_errors_fatal: true
  become: true
  roles:
    - role: test
```

```
Role Sample

---
- block:
    - include_tasks: test.yml
      any_errors_fatal: true
      run_once: true
```

```
Task Sample

---
 - name: Test
   block:
    - name: Transfer files from node1 to node2
      copy:
        src: /tmp/a
        dest: /tmp/
      delegate_to: node2

  delegate_to: node1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **no**: you will not be able to do this with the `copy` module.

You might however want to have a look at the [`synchronize` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/synchronize_module.html)

Quoting the doc

> The “local host” can be changed to a different host by using delegate_to. This enables copying between two remote hosts or entirely on one remote machine.

You would basically end up with something like:

```
---
- name: Rsync some files
  hosts: my_target_host

  tasks:
    - name: copy my file
      synchronize:
        src: path/on/source/host
        dest: path/on/dest/host
      delegate_to: my_source_host
```

**Edit** I just found [this article](https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/how-to-copy-files-between-remote-servers-ansible-fetch-sync/) referencing `synchronize` as well as the [`fetch`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fetch_module.html#fetch-module)/copy method that you might want to look at.

Answer (score 4):

You can use synchronize module only when rsync is enabled either in source server (kube master in your case) or in the kube nodes.

#### Method 1: to push from master, need rsync enabled in master

Synchronize use `push` mode by default

```
- hosts: nodes
  tasks:
    - name: Transfer file from master to nodes
      synchronize:
        src: /src/path/to/file
        dest: /dest/path/to/file
      delegate_to: "{{ master }}"
```

#### Method 2: to use fetch and copy modules

```
 - hosts: all
   tasks:
     - name: Fetch the file from the master to ansible
       run_once: yes
       fetch: src=/src/path/to/file dest=temp/ flat=yes
       when: "{{ ansible_hostname == 'master' }}"
     - name: Copy the file from the ansible to nodes
       copy: src=temp/file dest=/dest/path/to/file
       when: "{{ ansible_hostname != 'master' }}"
```

Hope this helps.